# IOS: Firebase Phone Authentication stops working suddenly in test flight

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am working on a flutter application that uses Firebase Phone Number Authentication (SMS OTP). It is working perfectly on Android but having issues with the iPhone. I am testing with a real device. I am able to login with the phone number several times after installing the application. But after some time, I am not able to login with the same mobile number and it asks me to check the number correctly. The sim is on the same phone that I am testing in. The phone login is not working in a simulator or real device while debugging and hence I am having trouble figuring out this issue. Has anybody experienced such weird behaviour before? I am using flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.9 and firebase_auth 0.15.3+1 version. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
_verifyPhoneNumber(BuildContext context) async {

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    timeout: Duration(seconds: 0),
    verificationCompleted: (authCredential) =>
        _verificationComplete(authCredential, context),
    verificationFailed: (authException) =>
        _verificationFailed(authException, context),
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) =>
        _codeAutoRetrievalTimeout(verificationId),
    // called when the SMS code is sent
    codeSent: (verificationId, [code]) =>
        _smsCodeSent(verificationId, [code])); }



_verificationComplete(AuthCredential authCredential, BuildContext context) {
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
if (!smsCodeSent) handleLogin(authCredential);}



 _verificationFailed(AuthException authException, BuildContext context) {
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => AnimatedDialog(), // SHows diaglog box with check your number error message);}



_smsCodeSent(String verificationId, List<int> code) {
smsCodeSent = true;
_smsVerificationCode = verificationId;
smsOTPDialog(context)  }


 _codeAutoRetrievalTimeout(String verificationId) {
// set the verification code so that we can use it to log the user in
_smsVerificationCode = verificationId;}

  smsOTPDialog(BuildContext context) {
Navigator.of(context).push(
    _createRoute(userPhoneNumber, _smsVerificationCode, _fullname.text));}
```

Comment: Firebase gives some guidance to do with testing of phone auth. There could be some rate limiting / spam prevention going on? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers

Answer (score 1):

You should get your number setup inside the phone authentication sign method as a test phone number. Firebase Auth will block your phone number from using the services when it detects that your phone number is calling the services repeatedly. They flag it then block it for almost 4hours. Phone authentication has a rate limit of around 5 calls per hour for every phone number.

Try checking that out.

Comment: I get that is the issue, but whenever I close the application it points me towards the screen where I type the OTP and then I get the OTP. I should not be getting the OTP every time I open the app for the real number. It works perfectly on Androids i.e it logins without OTP by itself. Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Can you add the code that checks for authentication?

Comment: You should check whether the user is logged in then send the authentication request. If the above code is in your application entry you should have a check for the state of the user and find out if they already registered.

Comment: I am actually managing those things. Like I said it is working well with Android. It checks and does not sends OTP again and again. But thanks